# Text Format in Text Box asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a text box 
where user can reply through it

i should post as same way user enters

For Example

if users uses enter between text i should post as same way

```
test comment
test comment
```

it should be posted on same way...

Comment: I think he doesn't want to lose newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a textarea instead of a text input you should maintain linebreaks.